# Undefined reference in C with the open computer vision

Tags: c, opencv, camera, makefile, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to test an example using the raspberry pi camera board with opencv. The code is from https://github.com/robidouille/robidouille/blob/master/raspicam_cv/RaspiCamCV.c

When typing `make` I get the error :

> Undefined reference to symbol `cvSaveImage`

I have the header that contains the function `cvSaveImage`. When I don't use `cvSaveImage` it compiles successfully.

How do i know wich libraries are missing? Here is my output of `pkg-config opencv --libs`:

> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_viz.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so -ltbb -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl

*Update*: `cvSaveImage` is in `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.0.0`. I have a makefile but i don't know how to resolve the error from it.

Comment: What library contains the cvSaveImage() function?   Have you included the path and 'short' library names in the makefile statement that links everything together?  Do you have a MakeFile?  Where is the cvSaveImage() called from?  It is not mentioned in the referenced code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to correct spelling mistakes and improve formatting and readability - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Also please provide any additional information asked by editing in your question rather than using comments. Good luck!

Comment: thanks i'm  not a native english speaker :p

Answer (score 0):

See output of pkg-config opencv --libs to find out what libraries you're missing, then add them to your config. For more information visit [OpenCV 2.4.1 undefined references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202156/opencv-2-4-1-undefined-references)

Comment: i have updated the question after doing pkg-config opencv --libs

Comment: Now link those libraries , be sure to link correct libraries , if you are using 32 bit OS then link libraries that are inside x86 folder. Copy all .dll files from bin folder to gcc-bin folder and run :)

Comment: plz can you tell me how to link all those libraries , and where can  i find the gcc-bin folder . NB : i'm using ubuntu 14.04 64 bits

Comment: i have done : g++ -o example example.cpp `pkg-config --static --cflags --libs opencv` ... compiled successfully but when running i get the same error :error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_calib3d.so.3.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  => any other solutions plz

Comment: Well i use windows OS & devc++ as gui , i don't know much about linking libraries in gcc through command line..well at last read this , may be this will help http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_C_libraries.html  if problem continue then msg me to https://www.facebook.com/udit.tutu  my friend who uses ubuntu will help you